# How should RESTful calls return for failure messages?

Tags: rest, http

Assuming RESTful call needs to indicate the request has been accepted successfully, but the content information conflicts with existing data.

For example, trying to insert a new user, and a response needs to tell the user exists, and I am looking for a proper way of doing it in RESTful.
First option I have is using the return code as 200 status, but the content says the request is returned as failure and its description.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
.
.

{"status":"failure", "message":"User exists already"}
```

Another option is to change HTTP response code something other than 200 status, and only inject the description in JSON Object.

```
HTTP/1.1 409 Conflict
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
.
.

{"message":"User exists already"}
```

In order to generalize the question, should RESTful be JSON content oriented or HTTP status code oriented for exception handling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With REST you must always leverage status codes within responses to indicate what happens. It's the case for successful responses (status codes `2xx` and `3xx`) or error ones (`4xx` and `5xx` ). Moreover, in the case of errors, if a specific status code is too generic (for example data validation on a specific content field with status code `400` or `422`), you can return additional hints to give more hints within the response payload. The structure of the latter is up to you... What you use within your second snippet is perfect ;-)

This link (section "Error handling") could give you more hints at this level: https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: How about if there are more than one error types in the same request, and it is needed to act differently based on a response? In that case, would it be better with different HTTP status or content of the response should tell what to do next?